# Proving that a function is injective and strictly increasing

Tags: calculus, functions, proof-writing, proof-explanation

I have recently started doing proofs, and I find it quite hard to construct one. I am not really clear on how proofs should generally look like. What information should it include? 
Are we always need to suppose something is true and then arrive at the conclusion that our assumption along with the reasonings we provided imply something else (what's asked from us to be proved?)
 More specifically, questions such as these two are perfect examples of questions that I am not sure what I am supposed to show in a format of a proof.

1. Let *I ⊆ ℝ* be an interval. We say that a function *f: I → ℝ* is strictly increasing if whenever $a,b ∈ I$ satisfy $a < b$, then $f(a) < f(b)$. Show that a strictly increasing function is injective.

That's what I have done: 
Given that a function is increasing for some a,b ∈ R, assume a≠b. Since the function is strictly increasing, then $a < b$, which would also imply that $f(a)<f(b)$. Therefore, this shows that $f(a)≠f(b)$ and that the function is injective as needed to be shown.

2. Suppose *f: I → ℝ* is strictly increasing if whenever $a,b ∈ I$ satisfy $a < b$, then $f(a) < f(b)$. Show that $f^{-1}$ is also strictly increasing.

For this question, should I apply the same reasoning as that above, and add that taking the inverse of that function wouldn't change the fact that $a < b$? Would that be sufficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right ideas, but you need to be more rigorous in how you make the arguments.

Let's start with the definition of being injective. A function is injective when for all $a,b$ in the domain, $a\neq b\to f(a)\neq f(b)$. So, let $a\neq b$. By the law of trichotomy, $a<b$ or $a>b$. Without loss of generality let $a<b$. Then, by assumption, we have that $f(a)<f(b)\to f(a)\neq f(b)$, which is what we desired.

For the second proof, we write down the definition of a strictly increasing function. For any $a,b$ in the domain where $a<b$, $f(a)<f(b)$. So, consider $c,d$ in the domain of $f^{-1}$ such that $c<d$. By definition of the inverse, there exists $a,b$ in the domain of $f$ such that $f(a)=c,\;f(b)=d$. We seek to show that $a < b$. We know that $f^{-1}$ is a bijection, so $a\neq b$. By the law of trichotomy, $a<b$ or $a>b$. If $a>b$, then by assumption, $f(c)>f(d)$, a contradiction. Hence, $a<b$ as desired.

Comment: For the second question, would a direct proof be possible? (In the form $p⟹q$)

Comment: @HarryBattersby Haven't thought about it. Is proof by contradiction a problem?

Comment: No, I'm just trying to think of all the possible ways that these statements can be proved. I am new to proofs, so I am just trying to wrap my head around different prove methods.

Comment: A slightly simpler version, can leave out "By the law of trichotomy, a<b
 or a>b".  I think most professors would accept simply "Without loss of generality let a<b"

Comment: Note: This sentence "Since the function is strictly increasing, then a<b
, which would also imply that f(a)<f(b)." is likely to be misinterpreted.
It sounds too much like, "( ... strictly increasing implies a < b) ..."

Of course that's not what vadimtimb means, but it's much better to prevent any possible misinterpretations.  Even something like 

"Since the function is strictly increasing, then ( a<b would also imply that f(a)<f(b)  )" prevents the logical error.
.